# Overriding keypress event during autocomplete select event

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, tabs, keydown, preventdefault

```
$('#MyField').autocomplete({
    select: function(event, ui) {
        var selectedObj = ui.item; 

$('#FieldToSet').val(ui.item.id);
$('#FieldForNextFocus').focus();
        }
```

I was using autocomplete, and I wanted to jump specifically to another field after the complete event. So I set focus(). But, the set focus actually fires first, and then the keypress event that triggered the autocomplete fires. So if the user autocompleted with the Enter key or Mouse click, all was fine, but if they used TAB to select the item, it would set focus to my new field and then the tab would execute, taking them one field too far..

I tried inserting:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

after my set focus() but that stops the field from populating on a click event for some reason. So, I think I need to just call event.preventDefault() if the 'TAB' key was pressed for the autocomplete select method to fire. I can't figure out how to find out what was pressed inside of the select.